# How to generate the hash of a transaction?

Tags: transactions

How can I generate an ID of a transaction before submitting it to an RPC node? I know I can get a transaction signature as a result of [web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#sendAndConfirmTransaction) call but is it possible to generate the signature deterministically?

Comment: Transaction IDs on Solana are signatures (`signature[0]`), not hashes.  I'd suggest updating your question to clarify this fact and avoid propagating misinformation

Comment: This was supposed to be a question from a person who comes from EVM background (who from my perspective comprise the bigger part of devs coming to Solana).

Comment: No sense misinforming them.  Accuracy is key to understanding

Answer (score 5):

You can manually sign the transaction before sending it, and then retrieve signature:

```
const bs58 = require('bs58');

// build a transaction
const transaction = new Transaction(...);

// sign it explicitly
transaction.sign(...signers);

// retrieve the signature as base58
const signature = bs58.encode(transaction.signature())
```

You will need to already have a blockhash defined and set against the transaction for this to work.

This will not work with `sendTransaction`, which re-signs everything. So serialize the message directly to send:

```
const message = transaction.serialize();
connection.sendRawTransaction(message)
```