# Will two transactions with the same instructions and accounts always have the same Transaction ID?

Tags: transactions, signature

I was debugging an issue in our backend where two parallel transaction ended up having the same Transaction ID.

This is what Solana docs say about the Transaction ID:

> **Transaction ID**
> The first signature in a transaction, which can be
> used to uniquely identify the transaction across the complete ledger.

Here's an excerpt from the docs for `sendTransaction` RPC call:

> The returned signature is the first signature in the transaction,
> which is used to identify the transaction (transaction id).
> This identifier can be easily extracted from the transaction data
> **before submission**.

Does this mean that the transaction signature doesn't depend on the on chain state?

If I have a transaction with an instruction `AddOne` which does something like `program_data.x += 1`, the instruction data will be constant right? So the transaction signature will also be the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate the hash of a transaction?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/22/how-to-generate-the-hash-of-a-transaction)

Comment: No it just shows the steps of retrieving the signature from the JS transaction object before sending it.

Comment: The transaction ID _is_ the first signature (that of the fee-payer) of a transaction

Comment: Or perhaps the question should be reworded to instead ask which data the signature covers?

Comment: I have reworded the title :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The signature is a 64-byte ed25519 signature, which is a hash, based on the instructions and a recent (latest) blockhash. This blockhash makes the signature unique from other identical instructions. It indeed does not depend on the on-chain state of any account info.

It's therefore possible that a transaction is signed two times with an identical blockhash. This can practically happen if you create a burst of transactions, for instance in a parallel application.

Comment: So we can send only one transaction with the same data per block?

Comment: Same hash (signature) per block. Yes. If you want to send more instructions in one block, just add extra instructions to your transaction.

Comment: Please take care when referring to Solana transaction IDs, they are always signatures and never hashes.  In my experience, some folks confuse this terminology with the transaction's `recent_blockhash` field, which is used as a cluster-specific nonce

Comment: I briefly adapted the answer. Though, in my opinion a signature is still a hash, but I understand the confusion it can cause.

Comment: @itsfarseen technically you could just use a different blockhash as the recent_blockhash - you can gather a rolling couple hundred valid recent blockhashes at any given time.